# Counter value is not working properly after first attempt in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having bootstrap modal in which I have made it close automatically after 7 seconds and which is working fine till here.

My problem is I have shown counter seconds also under modal and which is working fine in the first attempt. **But** after the first attempt instead of starting from 0 seconds it starts from any random number. I don't know what I am missing in it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.thank_you_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {

    var myModal = $(this);
    clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));
    myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function() {
      myModal.modal('hide');
    }, 7000));

    var sec = 0;

    function pad(val) {
      return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(++sec % 60);
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }, 7000);




  });
});
```

```css
#custom_modal .modal-content+span {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#custom_modal">Click me</a>

<!--.......... Modal ..........-->
<div class="modal fade thank_you_modal" id="custom_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h2>Thank You</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span>This message will close in <span id="seconds">00</span> seconds</span>
  </div>
</div>
<!--............Modal Ends........-->
```

[Working Code in Codepen](https://codepen.io/shutterwithfocus/pen/awGxwE)

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me in the codepen you provided !

```
$(function(){
    $('.thank_you_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){

        var myModal = $(this);
        clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));
        myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
            myModal.modal('hide');
        }, 7000));

 var sec = 7;   

function pad(val) {
    return val > 2 ? val : "0" + val;
}
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = pad(--sec % 60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10));
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    sec = 7;
}, 7000);




    });
});
```

The problem is that you forget to reinitialize your "sec" to 7 (for countdown effect) !